# Assignment operator with plus mark. (not addition assignment operator)

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have just started studying D3 and was following https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3371592.

It has the following line.

width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right

I'm wandering what's the importance of the  '+' mark in front of svg.

I checked the value of width with and without the '+' mark. Results of the both were same.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'ts a short form to convert a string to a number. Try in the Javascript console:

```
> +"10"
10
```

The caveat in this case is that while `svg.attr("width")` always returns a string, it may have a unit like `"50px"` or `"20%"`. The above form then will not work, and would not handle the value correctly anyway, if the unit is anything but `px`.